Question about Package Inclusion and User Creation in Kolla Base Image
I'm currently reading through the OpenStack Kolla source code, and I noticed a few design choices in the "kolla/base" image that I’d like to understand better:

The kolla/base The image includes several packages (such as Apache) that don’t appear necessary for most containers.
Additionally, user and group accounts for all services are created in the base image, even though all containers don’t use them.

Could someone explain the reasoning behind including these components in the base image? Is there any documentation available that provides insight into the design approach for Kolla images?
